# Yii2 Button for show Modal Form only work once

Tags: php, yii2, bootstrap-modal

I have a button to call Modal Form to create new Approval Letter.
I add that button in **form.php**.
This is the code:

```
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;

.....
<?php
Modal::begin([
    'header' => '<h4>Create New Approval</h4>',
    'id' => 'modal',
    'size' => 'modal-lg'
]);
echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";
Modal::end();
?>

<div class="company-form">
<p><?= Html::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> New Approval', ['value' => Url::to('../company/create-modal'), 'class' => 'btn btn-add-al', 'id' => 'modalButton']) ?></p>
.....
</div>
```

and this is jquery function:

```
$(function () {
    $('#modalButton').click(function () {
         $('#modal').modal('show')
            .find('#modalContent')
            .load($(this).attr('value'));
    });
});
```

I have issue, that is the button only work once. So, when I click the button, it will show Modal Form, and if I click outside the Modal Form, the Modal Form automatically closed, and when I try to click again, the button won'didn't work. It can work again when I refresh the page.

Why it's happen? and how to fix it?

Comment: How did you created the modal, by hand or using yii\bootstrap\Modal? Are you using some jquery to open this modal?     
Can you give more info regarding how are you working with the modal? More code, to try to replicate the problem, please.

Comment: I'm using yii\bootstrap\Modal. Ana using jquery for show the modal. I've update the code. Please check it out. Thanks

Comment: are you using pjax? maybe you wrapped the whole modal form, instead content only.

Answer (score 1):

I am using your code in my test bed, and actually it works perfectly.
I have the feeling you might be having a problem regarding where jquery is loading.

By default, jquery loads on the footer of your page, that means that if you are placing your script in the middle of your page it might be responsible of some problems. So please test the following.

1. Load jquery and other scripts on the header, by adding the following on config\web.php. If it solves the problem you can work later on placing your script inside a js file and load it after jquery.

   ```
   'components' => [
   'assetManager' => [
       'bundles' => [
           'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
               'jsOptions' => [ 'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD ],
           ],
       ],
   ```
2. Place your script inside a document ready (just in case...)

   ```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
       console.log( "ready!" );
       $(function () {
           $('#modalButton').click(function () {
               $('#modal').modal('show')
                   .find('#modalContent')
                   .load($(this).attr('value'));
           });
       });
   });
   ```
3. I am using this imports in the view so I guess pjax is not a problem.

   use yii\widgets\Pjax;
   use yii\bootstrap\Modal;
   use yii\helpers\Html;
   use yii\helpers\Url;
4. Open your console on the browser «I am using chrome» `Ctrl+Shift+J (Windows o Linux) o Cmd+Opt+J (Mac)`. And if it fails post the result, it might be showing you an error or warning.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, sometimes it work until three times and then failed and show `TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function` in console, sometimes it show `TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function` in the second times.

Comment: What @natral is saying it sometimes a very common problem, when jquery is loaded more than ones, can you check?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before and it was because my jquery script was being loaded more than once on the page. Check in your browser's developer tools or use yii's asset toolbar to see what assets are being loaded. Yii2 by default loads jQuery so if you manually add it (maybe you want a newer version) then this could lead to conflicts like these. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change your js to:

```
$(function () {
    /** @params this - document **/
    $(this).on('click', '#modalButton', function () {
        $('#modal').modal('show')
            .find('#modalContent')
            .load($(this).attr('value'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$('#modalButton').click(function () {`, you need to bind the `click` event with the document:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#modalButton", function () {
         $('#modal').modal('show')
            .find('#modalContent')
            .load($(this).attr('value'));
    });
});
```